# Data insertion in already created table in sql using mobile first studio

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

kindly need ur help.i have copy pasted and modified the  below project from idan adar post about inserting data .i already have an table with 2 rows of data and i need to add an additional one into it .although everything looks fine i cant able to insert data into table. no error also is showed in console help please folks,thanks in advance
index.html

```
<html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title>demo2</title>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
            <!--
                <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.png">
                <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="images/apple-touch-icon.png"> 
            -->
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
            <script>window.$ = window.jQuery = WLJQ;</script>
        </head>
        <body style="display: none;">
            <!--application UI goes here-->
            <h1>Please Enter The Student Details</h1>
 <form >    
student id:<input type="number"  id="stdid"  ><br><br>
student name<input type="text" id= "stdname"  > <br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Register" onclick="insertValuesToDB();">

</form>
            <script src="js/initOptions.js"></script>
            <script src="js/main.js"></script>
            <script src="js/messages.js"></script>
        </body>
</html>
```

main.js

```
function wlCommonInit(){    
}
function insertValuesToDB(){
     var invocationData = {
               adapter:"Insertadap",
                  procedure:"insertvaluesprocedure",
                  parameters:[$('#stdid').val(),$('#stdname').val()]
             };


     WL.client.invokeProcedure(invocationData,{
         onSuccess :loadFeedsSuccess1,
        onFailure :loadFeedsFailure1,
     });
    }

    function loadFeedsSuccess1() {

    alert("success");


     }

    function loadFeedsFailure1() {
    alert("failure");

    }
```

adapter.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
    Licensed Materials - Property of IBM
    5725-I43 (C) Copyright IBM Corp. 2011, 2013. All Rights Reserved.
    US Government Users Restricted Rights - Use, duplication or
    disclosure restricted by GSA ADP Schedule Contract with IBM Corp.
-->
<wl:adapter name="Insertadap"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:wl="http://www.ibm.com/mfp/integration"
    xmlns:sql="http://www.ibm.com/mfp/integration/sql">

    <displayName>Insertadap</displayName>
    <description>Insertadap</description>
    <connectivity>
        <connectionPolicy xsi:type="sql:SQLConnectionPolicy">
            <!-- Example for using a JNDI data source, replace with actual data source name -->
            <!-- <dataSourceJNDIName>java:/data-source-jndi-name</dataSourceJNDIName> -->

            <!-- Example for using MySQL connector, do not forget to put the MySQL connector library in the project's lib folder -->
            <dataSourceDefinition>
                <driverClass>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driverClass>
                <url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:****/hello</url>
                <user>****</user>
                <password>***</password> 
            </dataSourceDefinition>
        </connectionPolicy>
    </connectivity>

    <!-- Replace this with appropriate procedures -->
    <procedure name="insertvaluesprocedure"/>
    <procedure name="procedure2"/>

</wl:adapter>
```

ADAP imp.js

```
var  users = WL.Server.createSQLStatement("INSERT INTO studentdb(stdid,stdname) VALUES(?,?)");
 function insertvaluesprocedure(stdid,stdname) {
return WL.Server.invokeSQLStatement({
    preparedStatement : users,
    parameters : [stdid,stdname]
 });
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

When previewing the application in Chrome and Chrome DevTools are open and you use the app - what is the error that you see in the Chrome DevTools console?

Additionally, the error may just be that you declared in the adapter XML a procedure "procedure2", but in your client code you are calling "procedure1".

Change "procedure1" to "procedure2".

---

Edit: based on the comments it appears to be a type mistmatch.

Assuming the stdid is supposed to correspond to the int field in the database, this will obviously be a problem because in JavaScript by default it is treated as a string.

So you have two options:

1. In your database, change int to varchar
2. In your JavaScript, do something like `var stdid = stdid * 1;`, which should then change it to number, and then it will likely be accepted by the database.

Comment: my adapter itself showing a problem {
   "errors": [
      "Runtime: Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'studid' at row 1.\nPerformed query:\nINSERT INTO studentdb(studid,studname) VALUES(?,?)"
   ],
   "info": [
   ],
   "isSuccessful": false,
   "warnings": [
   ]
}

Comment: Sounds like you have a type mismatch in your database compared to what you are giving it. In JavaScript it is always string, but it could be that you expect int, so you could change your database to expect string.

Comment: my db just 2 field int and varchar field . What i need to do

Comment: What is the int and what is the varchar? Which is the stdid and which is the  stdnam? I don't read your mind, you know.

Comment: In mysql i have two fields integer stdid and varchar stdname just wanna enter a data into these fields through the ibm mobilefirst

Comment: am getting a new error Unexpected identifier 'nullnull' on line 1, column 23   is this an mysql error ???

Comment: How in the heck am I supposed to know? you do not provide anything to work with, so I don't know. Change the column type in the database to varchar.

Comment: Why does your client side code have "WL.Server.invokeProcedure".
Can you try the sample : http://javatechig.com/ibm-worklight/invoking-adapter-procedure-in-ibm-worklight

Comment: @VivinK sry that was a mistake i changed it . i am facing adapter error  error Unexpected identifier 'nullnull' on line 1, column 23 whats this i have changed my db datatype both into varchar.

Comment: The error is supposed to also mention the file the error has occurred at. Which?

Comment: @IdanAdar when running the adapter the error occurs

Comment: {
   "errors": [
      "I O: Unexpected identifier 'nullnull' on line 1, column 23"
   ],
   "info": [
   ],
   "isSuccessful": false,
   "warnings": [
   ]
}

Comment: Cannot invoke procedure InsertAdap/insertvaluesprocedure [project mydemo2]
Unexpected identifier 'nullnull' on line 1, column 23

Comment: Remove the `<form>` and `</form>` from the HTML.

Comment: idan as you said removed.but how it is connected to adapter ??done again getting same error

Comment: acturally MFconsole shows procedure invocation finished but MFSconsole shows the null null error message

Comment: I don't see this error. I used your code as-is with a MySQL database. In the database stdin is "int" and stdname is "varchar". The number value from HTML is inserted as well as the txt value. The only thing I changed was removing the form from the HTML.

Comment: @IdanAdar sir have you used any null constraint while creating table fields

Comment: No I did not. Anyway, this is clearly not related to MFP now.

Comment: just last question sir i have already two rows of data whether this may be the problem

Comment: Try removing them and test